# Vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ VS over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking at Q4 Exercise 2B in *Linear Algebra Done Right*. I got the answer but need some help to understand what is the difference if I change $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

(a)

Let $U$ be the subpace of $\mathbb{C}^5$ defined by $$U = \{(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5) \in \mathbb{C}^5 : 6z_1 = z_2 \text{ and } z_3 +2z_4 + 3z_5 = 0\}$$
Find a basis of $U$

(b)

Extend the basis  in part (a) to a basis of $\mathbb{C}^5$

(c)

Find a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{C}^5$ such that $\mathbb{C}^5 = U \oplus W$

I actually finished this question without considering subspace  as $\mathbb{C}^5$. Is there any potential problem or details I have missed?

Comment: You can identify $\Bbb C^n$ with $\Bbb R^{2n}$, so the only difference is that a basis $\{\beta_i\}$ over $\Bbb C$ would be a basis $\{\Re\beta_i,\Im\beta_i\}$ when considered as a basis over $\Bbb R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential idea here is that we can extend any $n$-dimensional real vector space to a $n$-dimensional complex vector space - and any basis of the old vector space will also be a basis of the new one.

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Then $V\oplus iV$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Addition is defined in the obvious way $(u+iv)+(u'+iv')=u+u'+i(v+v)$, while scalar multiplication is defined by $(a+ib)(u+iv) = (au-bv) + i(bu+av)$.

Theorem: If $\{w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n\}$ is a basis of the real vector space $V$, then $\{w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n\}$ is also a basis for the complex vector space $V\oplus iV$.
Proof: First, that the $w_k$ are linearly independent. If $\sum_k c_kw_k=\sum_k (a_k+ib_k)w_k = 0$ where $c_k=a_k+ib_k$ is the decomposition of the complex scalar $c_k$ into real and imaginary parts, then $\sum_k a_kw_k = 0$ and $\sum_k b_kw_k = 0$. By linear independence of the $w_k$ over $\mathbb{R}$, all of the $a_k$ and $b_k$ are zero. That's linear independence over $\mathbb{C}$.
Second, that the $w_k$ span $V\oplus iV$. Let $u+iv$ be an arbitrary vector in $V\oplus iV$. Since the $w_k$ span $V$, there are real scalars $a_k$ and $b_k$ so that $\sum_k a_kw_k=u$ and $\sum_k b_kw_k=v$. Then $\sum_k a_kw_k + i\sum_k b_kw_k =\sum_k (a_k+ib_k)w_k=u+iv$ and $u+iv$ is in the complex span of the $w_k$.

And now, to apply this. You found a basis for the subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^5$ satisfying that linear system. By the theorem above, this basis is also a basis for the complex vector space $V\oplus iV\subset \mathbb{C}^5=\mathbb{R}^5\oplus \mathbb{R}^5$. Is $V\oplus iV$ equal to $U$?

Yes, it is. Since those linear equations have real coefficients, they split over real and imaginary parts. Write $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5) = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)+i(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5)$ with the $x_k$ and $y_k$ real. We have $6z_1=z_2$ if and only if both $6x_1=x_2$ and $6y_1=y_2$, and similarly for the other equation. For any $z\in U$, its real and imaginary parts are both in $V$, and vice versa.

A [reference link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Extension_of_scalars) for this process. It can be done for any field extension, with the formal version based on tensor products.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's likely that there would be any problems, but you might want to run over your work and just check that every step is still valid over $\mathbb{R}$.

I can tell you that I have occasionally seen places where an argument is carried out for $\mathbb{R}$ followed by the author commenting that the same argument works identically for $\mathbb{C}$. And I don't know if you've seen any fields of finite characteristic yet, but if you have I'll bet that your argument would also work for any $F^5$ so long as $char(F) \ne 2$ and $char(F) \ne 3$.

Mind you I'm just saying this based on what I assume your work looks like. If you want to be more certain you'll need to post more of your details.